# Html5 canvas how to generate multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Im making a simple zombie game in html5 canvas and wanted to know how to create a zombie every x seconds in a random place? so far i have

```
var zombies = new Array();

function SummonZombies (){
    TotalZombies++;
    zombies[TotalZombies] = new Image();
    zombies[TotalZombies].src = 'images/monster.png';
    ctx.drawImage(zombies[TotalZombies], zombie_x, zombie_y);
}
```

Only one zombie is being created with this? how would i get it to generate more.

Comment: Use `setInterval()` perhaps? `zombieScheduler = setInterval(SummonZombies,x * 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, where are you declaring the variable TotalZombies?

Try something like this :

```
var zombies = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   var zombie = new Image();
   zombie.src = 'images/monster.png';
   ctx.drawImage(zombie, Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1), Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1));
   zombies.push(zombie);
}
```

This will create 100 zombies, with random x and y positions between 1 and 100. It will add each zombie to the zombies array after they have been instantiated.

Comment: You can change the random positioning code to work within the bounds of your canvas stage - ie use the canvas width / height to determine the limits of the numbers you are generating. Also like @squeamish-ossifrage said you can use setInterval to decide when to call this function so the zombies aren't all created at once.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but one more question after the for loops ends it seems to destroy all instances of the zombies it created??? am i missing something?

Comment: Perhaps you can link to a gist of all the javascript you're calling? It's hard for me to say for certain what's going on without seeing the code. If they are being removed from the canvas they're most likely being drawn over or the canvas is being cleared.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through `zombies` array, and invoke `drawImage()` on everyone.

**Extra tip**: remember to change `x` and `y` after all iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You must separate a Zombi from your zombies :
create a class that will describe what a Zombi is, and only after you will define a collection of such lovely guys and girls :

```
 // This Class defines what a Zombi is.
 function Zombi(x,y) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
 }

 var ZombiImage = new Image();
 ZombiImage.src = "images/monster.png";

 // image of a zombi is shared amongst all zombies, so it is
 // defined on the prototype
 Zombi.prototype.image = ZombiImage;

 // draw the zombi on provided context
 Zombi.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
      ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y);
 }
```

Now for the collection :

```
// This class defines a collection of Zombies.
function Zombies() {
     this.zombies = [];
}

// summons a zombi at a random place. returns the summoned zombi.
myZombies.prototype.summon() {
   var randX = Math.random()*100;
   var randY = Math.random()*100;
   return this.summonAt(randX, randY);
}

// summons a zombi at x,y. returns the summoned zombi.
myZombies.prototype.summonAt = function (x,y) {
   var newZombi = new Zombi(x,y);  
   this.zombies.push();
   return newZombi;
}

// draws all zombies on provided context.
myZombies.prototype.drawAll = function (ctx) {
    var i=0;
    var __zombies = this.zombies;
    for (;i<__zombies.length; i++) {
        __zombies[i].draw(ctx);
    }
}

// collection of all zombies for your game.
var zombies = new Zombies();

// here you can call zombies.summon(); or zombies.drawAll();
// and even zombies.summonAt(x,y);
```

In fact the code above is simplified : you must handle the onload event of the image to start the game only after the image was loaded.
But you should get the idea : separate the issues (handle ONE zombi vs a collection of zombies) will get you faster to your goal.
With this -simple- design, you'll be able to easily add-up behaviour to your zombies.

Just one more example in which i will add the seekBrain and walk behaviour :

```
 // This Class defines what a Zombi is.
 function Zombi(x,y) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.dirX = 0 ; // direction X
     this.dirY = 0;  // direction Y
     this.speed = 0.1; // common speed for all zombies
 }

 // have the zombi seek the brain located at (x,y)
 Zombi.prototype.seekBrain = function (x,y) {
    this.dirX = (x - this.x );
    this.dirY = (y - this.y );
    // normalize direction
    var norm = Math.sqrt( this.dirX*this.dirX + this.dirY*this.dirY  );
    this.dirX/=norm;
    this.dirY/=norm;
 }

 // Have the zombi walk in its current direction
 Zombi.prototype.walk = function() {
      this.x += this.dirX * this.speed;
      this.y += this.dirY * this.speed;
 }

 // image and draw remains the same
```

And now you might want for your collection :

```
// makes all zombies walk.
  Zombies.walkAll = function() {
    var i=0;
    var __zombies = this.zombies;
    for (;i<__zombies.length; i++) {
        __zombies[i].walk();
    }
}

// constructor, summon, summonAt, and drawAll remains the same.
```

So to summon a zombi at random place every xxx ms, do something like :

```
// summons a zombi at a random place every 2 seconds (==2000 ms)
setTimeInterval(2000, function() { zombies.summon(); } );
```

now, if hero.x and hero.y are what we guess, you can do :

```
// Have a random zombi hunt for hero's brain every 2 seconds
setTimeInterval(2000, function() { 
          var which = Math.floor(zombies.zombies.length * Math.random()); 
          zombies.zombies[which].seekBrain(hero.x, hero.y);
} );
```

provided you call to zombies.walkAll(); and zombies.drawAll(); on a regular basis, you've got the start of a game !  (i love so much zombies :-) )